# I want to get all characters after a specific character but at its last occurance

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

Want to get all the characters after a specific character but at its last occurrence.

Current 'CSM.Sales.0000.Territory Manager'
Desired Output : Territory Manager

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR('CSM.Sales.0000.Territory Manager', INSTR('CSM.Sales.0000.Territory Manager', '.') + 1) AS subject
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8aa54e2acaf62d047908b15418019e61)**

```
select substr('CSM.Sales.0000.Territory Manager', - 
    instr(reverse('CSM.Sales.0000.Territory Manager'), '.') + 1) from dual
```

OUTPUT:

```
Territory Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('CSM.Sales.0000.Territory Manager', '.',-1) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: seriously SUBSTRING_INDEX in oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR()` exactly does this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('CSM.Sales.0000.Territory Manager', '[^.]+$', 1, 1) AS subject
FROM dual;
```